# SQL Server ON DELETE CASCADE Error In Laravel

Tags: php, sql-server, database, laravel, cascading-deletes

I'm using Laravel Framework; I have multiple connected tables,

**User** Schema Table :

```
 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Article** Schema Table :

```
Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string("title");
        $table->string("slug")->unique();
        $table->text("cover");
        $table->text("body");
        $table->boolean("status")->default(1);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Comment** Schema Table :

```
        Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger("user_id");
        $table->foreign("user_id")->references("id")->on("users")->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger("article_id");
        $table->foreign("article_id")->references("id")->on("articles")->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->text("comment");
        $table->bigInteger("level");
        $table->boolean("status")->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

In the comments table I have this important code:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger("user_id");
        $table->foreign("user_id")->references("id")->on("users")->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger("article_id");
        $table->foreign("article_id")->references("id")->on("articles")->onDelete('cascade');
```

I want to when I delete an article or user, I would like to have their comments deleted when a user or an article is deleted, But this is a mistake in the SQL Server database.

**Error Form SQL Server Database**:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPA9O.jpg)

When I removed this method

> ->onDelete('cascade');

The error disappears.

I definitely need to have the corresponding method. Can anyone guide me to solve this problem?

Comment: Your problem is the constraint "article_favorite_user_id_foreign". Execute the suggested SQL code on image, directly on your MS SQL Server:  alter table articles_favorite add constraint  article_favorite_user_id_foreign on update cascade on delete cascade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a delete observer instead, `on delete cascade` is not the best thing to do.

Define the relationship in `User` model:

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function articles()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Article::class, 'user_id');
}
```

Then implement the `boot` method to observe the deletion of a record

```
protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($user) {
        $user->articles()->delete();
    });
}
```

You can loop on articles comments in the same method or do the same thing you did here with `Article` and `Comment` models

Read more about observers here https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#observers

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, also won't work for multiple deletes via the query.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using `cascade on delete` even for the `user` who access it. I don't think you need to delete the list even if the user who is not the creator but only have access to it. So update following

> **Change**

```
$table->foreign("user_id")->references("id")->on("users")->onDelete('cascade');
```

> **to**

```
$table->foreign("user_id")->references("id")->on("users")->onDelete('no action');
```