# Laravel/Bagisto On Cascade error when I use SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I'm using an e-commerce solution built on Laravel called Bagisto, I've managed to connect it to SQL Server, how ever when I run

```
php artisan migrate
```

I get the following errors:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'cart_items_parent_id_foreign' on table 'cart_items' may  cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

I know this is because SQL Server changes syntax on delete, so by adding 'no action' like below it works

```
$table->foreign('child_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('no action');
```

But there are a lot of tables with the same error, so is there like any other way to have 'cascade'

```
$table->foreign('child_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
```

without getting this errors?

Comment: This is probably related to this thread,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60582028/sql-server-on-delete-cascade-error-in-laravel